# How to populate JSON data using ngx-datatable in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-datatables, ngx-datatable

I am new to Angular 4 and i am trying to implement the ngx-datatble by following the approach defined in [ngx-datatable github](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/content/introduction/getting-started.html) and i am able to populate the table, however my confusion starts when i am trying to populate the data from a JSON object.
The row and column array are bonded with the "name" property and same is being shown as header. But in actual JSON we will have camel-case naming convention.How to populate that data with proper header.

Please advice, any help would be appreciated..!!!

Thanks in Advance

Please find my code below:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <ngx-datatable
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns">
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

**TS File**

```
rows = [
    { Firstname: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
    { name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
    { name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
];
columns = [
    { prop: 'Firstname' },
    { name: 'Gender' },
    { name: 'Company' }

];
```

**Target JSON**

```
[{
  "firstName":"abc",
  "lastName":"xyz",
  "address_1":"lorem ipsum",
  "address_2":"and so on"
},{
  "firstName":"abc",
  "lastName":"xyz",
  "address_1":"lorem ipsum",
  "address_2":"and so on"
},{
  "firstName":"abc",
  "lastName":"xyz",
  "address_1":"lorem ipsum",
  "address_2":"and so on"
}]
```

Comment: Check ngx-datatable in Angular 4 to 7 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860675/how-to-populate-json-data-using-ngx-datatable-in-angular-4

Answer (score 2):

```
columns = [
    { 
       prop: 'Firstname', // prop will bind to the json property
       name : 'First Name' // You can define the name here 
                          // ( Column label. If none specified, it will use the prop value and decamelize it. )
    },
    { name: 'Gender' },
    { name: 'Company' }

];
```

For More Detail : **[Read](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/content/api/column/inputs.html)**